# How do I check if shutdown proccess is running on my computer in C#?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to code program that shutdowns computer automatically in C#. User simply inserts hours and minutes and after that time computer will turn off. Everything is working, but I want to add 'status' message. I want it to show if shutdown proccess in computer is on or off. I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Did you know there's a `shutdown` command already? Check `shutdown /?` in cmd.exe

Comment: I know, I'm using that. The point is how to check in c# if shutdown proccess in computer is on. For example : I'm setting it on one hour, press OK and it says below something like "Status : Set", if i cancel it it says "Status: not Set"

Comment: Ok. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156216/detecting-a-scheduled-shutdown) it doesn't look easy/possible. You could just maintain your own state, and assume noone will schedule or abort shutdowns without using your program.

Comment: Use the [task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394806/327083).